# Parent work items estimate calculating in team foundation server 2013

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

Is there any way to calculate fields like Original estimate, Completed work in a parent work items.

I want to put in this field a total sum of it's child work items.

Comment: Which template are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013.3

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a server side plugin for TFS or create a Web Service that subscribe to TFS Events, then in your code you will use TFS API for the Client Object Model (Work Item Tracking) to get the needed work-items and its parent, calculate and save the data back to the work items

For more information see the following link:

[Extending the customization of TFS Process Template](http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2014/09/17/extending-the-customization-of-tfs-process-template/)

Comment: i thought about it. But i tried to find easier solution :)

Comment: Those are some nice tutorials you've put together there. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
I've download a TFSAggregator plugin from 
[Codeplex](http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com/)

Rebuilt it for TFS 2013 and it works!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. The project has been forked and is at https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator, including TFS2013 support and better aggregation options.

Comment: Yes, it works fine! :) So now we are waiting for multi-collections support :)) Thank you!

Comment: Multi-collection support is in the latest build available from https://ci.appveyor.com/project/giuliov/tfsaggregator. Builds for both TFS 2013 and 2015 are available for testing.